# Devise - how to check if reset password is token is valid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, devise-recoverable

I'm trying to figure out how I can check if a user reset token is valid BEFORE loading the reset password form. The issue is, currently users don't find out until after they submit.

Here is what I have

```
class PasswordsController < Devise::PasswordsController
before_action :check_valid_token

private

def check_valid_token
  resetCode = (params['resetCode'])
  reset_password_token = Devise.token_generator.digest(self, :reset_password_by_token, resetCode)
  user = User.find_by(reset_password_token: @reset_password_token)
  if user == nil
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
end
```

This doesn't work and I can't find much documentation.

Comment: Don't try this `User.find_by(reset_password_token: @reset_password_token)` looks risky. Let the user pass in his email and use that to find the record. The do `if params['resetCode'] == User.reset_password_token'`.

Comment: Hey, I changed it to that and then I got this

undefined method `reset_password_token' for #<Class:0x00007f9645051f30>

I'm sure I'm missing something and just new to this. Rails can't figure out what User.reset_password_token is.

Comment: Could it be that instead of passing `self` (which is an object of `PasswordsController`) you have to pass in `User` ? Thus: `Digest.token_generator.digest(User, ...)`

Answer (score 4):

Devise reset password token will be stored as hashed value. You need to decode it.

```
  def check_valid_token
    token = Devise.token_generator.digest(User, :reset_password_token, params['reset_password_token'])
    user = User.find_by(reset_password_token: token)
    user.present?
  end
```

This method will return, `true` or `false`

Answer (score 0):

I would do something basic, like this:

```rb
def check_valid_token
  @user = User.find_by!(reset_password_token: params[:token])
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
  redirect_to root_path
end
```

so you will have `@user` instance if token fits and if not it will redirect user to the `root_path`. You can also add some message before redirecting, like 
`flash.now[:error] = "Some message here"`

Comment: Hey! I did this and it's still not working. Any random token is I guess passing validation...?

Comment: `class PasswordsController < Devise::PasswordsController
before_action :check_valid_token, only: [:edit]

private

def check_valid_token
  @user = User.find_by!(reset_password_token: params[:token])
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
  redirect_to root_path
end
end`

That is my password controller

Comment: So what is wrong then? You don't retrieve user or what?

Comment: When I use that code, any token works. It's not verifying.